# nHibernate Method Delegate or Event is Expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, queryover

```
Client clientAlias = null;
Note noteAlias = null;
Comment commentAlias = null;

query.JoinAlias(() => noteAlias.Client, () => clientAlias)
.JoinAlias(() => noteAlias.Comments, () => commentAlias);
query.Where(() => clientAlias.Id == clientId);
query.OrderBy(() => clientAlias.Id).Desc();
```

This line is in error. Any guesses why?

```
query.OrderBy(() => clientAlias.Id).Desc();
```

The error says

```
Method Delegate or Event is Expected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not using

```
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Criterion;
```

Funny that resharper did not suggest that.

Comment: had the same issue, this time forgot the include Linq. No also no useful help from resharper.

Comment: Glad you could get some help from this :)